# Insert special character using :before pseudo class in css

Tags: html, css, encoding, special-characters, pseudo-class

I was toying around with the `:before` pseudo class in css, trying to insert a special character but the result is not what I was hoping for.

Using:

```
.read_more:before {
    content: "»";
    margin-right: 6px;
}
```

I get the character I want, but with an **Â** character before it and using:

```
.read_more:before {
    content: "&raquo;";
    margin-right: 6px;
}
```

I get the complete `&raquo;` on the html page.

I can think of a couple of ways to solve my problem, but I was wondering what the correct syntax would be if I wanted to use the `:before` pseudo class.

By the way, my doctype is:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
```

Comment: The answer to your problem is described in answers below and [here](https://alanhogan.com/tips/css/special-characters-in-generated-content), but in addition, I wanted to point out that `::before` has been the preferred selector, over `:before`, ever since since CSS3. The CSS3 syntax distinguishes between _pseudo-classes_ (like `:visited`) and _pseudo-elements_ (like `::first-line` and `::after`).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try specifying `<meta charset="utf-8">`. Ideally you want to set this in the server.

Comment: @Tae - http://static.medero.org/kak.html  the server dictates the encoding if it is not specified in the page itself... and because he didn't explicitly specify UTF-8 it's obvious he needs to.

Comment: This is a wrong answer. The mistake is using HTML entity in CSS code. You need to convert them; in this case: Â --> &#194;(html) --> \00C2 (css)

Comment: Ok what you actually want is a link to a conversion tool no? https://www.branah.com/unicode-converter

Answer (score 75):

try this

```
.read_more:before {
    content: "\00BB";
    margin-right: 6px;
}
```

\00BB is the unicode representation of that character. It should reasonably works =)

Comment: That’s right  I wrote at length about this in 2005 and updated that post with some tips: https://alanhogan.com/tips/css/special-characters-in-generated-content

Answer (score 26):

The answer has been already told, but I want to refer to:

> I get the complete `&raquo;` on the html page.

That's because CSS `content` property isn't treated as HTML. It's not appended to the DOM, therefore any HTML-specific markup isn't parsed. You can insert a character directly: `content: "Ԃ";` or use Unicode notation: `content: "\0504";`.

Comment: Thanks, that explains as well why I didn´t see it in Firebug.

Comment: Good explanation, this was the solution I needed.  Cheers!

Answer (score 10):

I know it's been a while since this question was asked but in case someone might need it nowadays, I found the solution for it.

[Here's](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/html/glyphs/) a chart with lots of glyphs. Find the one you want and copy the hex code for it.

Then paste it [here](http://www.evotech.net/articles/testjsentities.html) to convert.

You'll get a value that looks like this: \00E1 (CSS Value)

Paste this value on your 'content:' and be happy :)

Answer (score 2):

Your browser isn't using the correct text encoding -- that is, it isn't using the same text encoding as your editor. If you are receiving the page from a Web server, the best approach is to make sure the server is sending the proper Content-Type header. If you don't have control over the Web server's headers, or if you will be doing a lot of testing using local HTML files, add [appropriate tags](http://tlt.its.psu.edu/suggestions/international/web/tips/declare.html) to your document for the encoding and HTML version you are using. I recommend using UTF-8. The CSS file (if it is separate from the HTML) should use the same encoding.

Answer (score 1):

Add this on the html, inside the `<head>` section

```
<meta HTTP-EQUIV="content-type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

But if the html page is coded in PHP, I would prefer the following:

```
<?php
    header("Content-Encoding: utf-8");
    header("Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8");
?>
```

And don't forget to save any file (css, html, php) with UTF-8 encoding

Comment: Thanks, that's what I ended up doing when I saw @meder's answer.